# how to add application to autostart on bootup

Tags: boot, autostart

I have ubuntu 18.04 and there are two application I need to make sure are added to startup on bootup.

1. Printnode
2. TeamViewer

Can you someone tell me what I need to do to get this setup and to work?
I did see on the gui there is a startup folder, but never used it before.
Please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en) (which is searchable):

Tap the **Super** (AKA Windows) key and open Startup Applications
OR 
press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the command `gnome-session-properties` .

Click **Add** and enter the command to be executed at login (name and comment are optional). For example, to make Firefox start automatically, it's sufficient to type **firefox** in the Command field and confirm with Add.

Comment: I was able to get printnode working on reboot, however for some reason TeamViewer 14.6 does not see to start up on reboot.

Comment: Teamviewer was not much help but I did accomplish to get this to work. What I have to do was the following

Comment: Sorry had to add “sudo teamviewer —daemon  enable to the startup application folder that did the trick.